# Why are all communities unlinked?

Tags: discussion, linked-accounts

I examine questions on Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, and the subdomains for specializations. Every time I want to upvote or save a question or ask one on a new site, I am prompted to make a new account. Why??

I thought all of these sites were linked and each user should have one account that enables them to post to different specialty sites. This doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It is the same account, you just need to activate it for use on a new site. This has the advantage that you get your personal list of sites in the menu and on your profile page. It is also a performance consideration, there are 180 sites or so and you need to be in the database for each of them where you are a member - this is a lot of wasted space if you would automatically be signed up for all sites.

Comment: Furthermore it gives a good sense of the size of each individual site/community and the differences between them, see https://stackexchange.com/sites#users.